# Something's wrong when i create a new project vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am starting to learn vuejs and I have a problem while creating a vue project with terminal. As you can see in the picture, the loadDep status line keeps spinning without moving. Can someone help me solve this problem T.T

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr03X.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I can not see which command you have fired for installation in your image.

Please checkout the official Document's Installation Page for more In Depth Installation Information.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

Use VueCLI for Command Line Installation.

If you are installing Vuejs using the terminal you need to:

1. Firstly install NPM package manager.
2. Then run the command below to install VueCLI:

   ```
   npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global
   ```
3. After executing this command simply check if it works successfully by typing:

   ```
   vue -v
   ```

   It should print the vue version if it was successful.
4. Then you can create a Vue project by using following command:

   ```
   vue create [Your Project Name]
   ```

It is all provided on [VueCLI Site](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html).